# injecting service into controller not working

Tags: angularjs

[image]Am new to angularjs. I am trying to use angular service to post data but its throwing below error

angular.js:12520 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: frontendServiceddProvider <- frontendServicedd <- CustSignupCtrl

service.js

```
app.service('frontendService', function frontendService ($http, $q, $rootScope){

        var list = this;


        list.registerCust = function(data){
            var defer = $q.defer();

            $http({
                url: $rootScope.endPoint,
                method: "POST",
                data: data
            })
            .success(function(res){
                console.log("Successfull!");
                defer.resolve(res);
            })
            .error(function(err, status){
                console.log("Failed !");
            })

            return defer.promise;
        }

        return list;

    });
```

customer_signup.js

```
app.controller('CustSignupCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter','frontendService', '$http', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants',
  function('$scope', '$filter','frontendService', '$http','editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants'){


    $scope.pw1 = '';

    $scope.registerCustomer = function (data) {
      return frontendService.registerCust(data)
    }

    $scope.signupcustomer = function(){

      var payload= {
        first_name: $scope.custForm.fname,
        last_name: $scope.custForm.lname,
        phone: $scope.custForm.phone,
        email:$scope.custForm.email,
        username:$scope.custForm.username,
        password:$scope.custForm.pw1,
        usertype:3
      }
      console.log("inside function");
      $scope.registerCustomer(payload).then(function(data){
        notification.success(data.result);
      },function(err){
        notification.error("Error: contact system admin");
      });

    }
  }  
])
```

I have given reference of both js files in index.html.. not getting where am doing wrong.. can anyone help

Comment: Your injections on not proper. The variables should be analogous
'$scope','frontendService', '$filter', '$http', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants'.
Your function parameters must be in same order in the controller function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.controller('CustSignupCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'frontendService', '$http', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants',
  function($scope, $filter, frontendService, $http, editableOptions, editableThemes, notify, notification, $appConstants){

    $scope.pw1 = '';
});
```

Whatever you `inject` into controller, should be in the same order.
Remove quotes accross the injectables inside `function`.

Comment: thanks for reply.. its not working getting 2 errors  1)customer_signup.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string  2)angular.js:12520 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CustSignupCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot of your browser console? There should be some errors there.

Comment: Did you reorder the whatever you have `injected` before? It say that there is an error in line 2.. can you check whether you have missed a comma or a quote or etc?

Comment: app.controller('CustSignupCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter','frontendService', '$http', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants',
  function('$scope', '$filter','frontendService', '$http','editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants'){                                                            }  
])

Comment: this is what i used

Comment: Can you update your whole customer_signup.js in question in an with an update heading?

Comment: Nope.. error .. angular.js:12520 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: frontendServiceProvider <- frontendService <- CustSignupCtrl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124713/discussion-between-ravi-teja-and-nsr).

Answer (score 2):

This can be a *dependency injection mismatch* sort of problem

AngularJS injects object into the function as it sees them inside `[]`

For example if you declare a function inside your js file, say like this

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('maincntrl',function($scope){

});
var search = function($scope,searchtext,searchfilters,searchareas)
{
   return 'result'
}

console.log(angular.injector.annotate(search));
```

The result you shall get in your console will be

```
["$scope","searchtext","searchfilters","searchareas"]
```

AngularJS parses the function parameters as an *array*

It goes through each array elements and the moment it sees `"$scope"`, it injects scope `object` into that position

Now the syntax which you have used is basically used for [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))

So according to your declaration

```
app.controller('CustSignupCtrl', ['$scope','frontendService', '$filter','frontendService', '$http', 'editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants',
  function('$scope', '$filter','frontendService', '$http','editableOptions', 'editableThemes','notify','notification','$appConstants'){

});
```

So

```
$scope--> shall be injected into $scope
frontendService-->shall be injected into $filter
$filter--> shall be injected into frontendService
.
.
.
so on
```

Also the errors(which you mentioned in comments) are occurring because you have declared `function` parameters as `strings` in which case the dependency injection is not happening. Fixing these things shall solve your problem